# Angular error property checked does not exist on type Fix[]

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I am doing an Angular Material class assignment where I list a set of repair services with prices. The user can check which services they want. The user clicks Calculate, and an invoice window pops open, listing only the services they chose and the total. I can get my list to appear, but I'm having trouble grabbing the services that are checked. I populate the first list using an Observable in a service. Then I try using a pipe and filter to grab the checked items. But in my filter, I'm getting a 'Property checked does not exist on type Fix[]' error. Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

fix.ts

```
export interface Fix {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: string;
  checked: boolean;
}
```

fix.service.ts

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Fix } from './fix';

@Injectable()
export class FixService {

  fixes: Fix[] = [
    {id: 1, name: "Password Reset", price: "39.99", checked: false},
    {id: 2, name: "Spyware Removal", price: "99.99", checked: false},
    {id: 3, name: "RAM Upgrade", price: "129.99", checked: false},
    {id: 4, name: "Software Installation", price: "49.99", checked: false},
    {id: 5, name: "Tune-up", price: "89.99", checked: false},
    {id: 6, name: "Keyboard Cleaning", price: "45.00", checked: false},
    {id: 7, name: "Disk Clean-up", price: "149.99", checked: false},
  ];

  constructor() { }

  getFix(): Observable<Fix[]> {
    return of(this.fixes);
  }
}
```

base-layout.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <mat-card class="services-panel frm-services-panel">
    <mat-card-header class="frm-services-header">
      <mat-toolbar class="frm-services-toolbar">
        Available Services
      </mat-toolbar>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content class="frm-services-body">
      <mat-form-field class="frm-services-formfield">
        <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let fix of fixes | async" value="{{fix.name}} {{fix.price}}" [(ngModel)]="fix.checked">
          <div fxLayout="row">
            <div class="frm-services-name">
              {{ fix.name }}
            </div>
            <div class="rightSide">
              {{ fix.price }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions class="frm-login-actions">
      <button mat-raised-button class="btn-login button1" (click)="getCheckboxes()">Calculate</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

base-layout.component.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Fix } from '../fix';
import { FixService } from '../fix.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-layout',
  templateUrl: './base-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base-layout.component.scss'],
  providers: [FixService]
})
export class BaseLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  fixes: Observable<Fix[]>;

  constructor(private fixService: FixService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fixes = this.fixService.getFix();
  }

  get getCheckboxes() {
    return this.fixes
      .pipe(
        filter(f => f.checked == true),
        map(f => f.values));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using the async pipe in the template, the class does not have access to returned value of the observable. the benefits of the async pipe is to avoid having to manually subscribe to the observable. however, if you need access to the value in the class, you will need to manually subscribe to said observable. (keeping in mind to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy)

I did quick stackblitz here -> [quick sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnbafp). SElect the fixes and click calculate, and you see the list of selected options

if you really don't want to subscribe manually, you could make a change to your process to pass the currently selected fix on change for the input box, but that seems like a lot of extra work just to avoid a manual subscription.

Ideally I would suggest using formGroup easily access the state of your controls.